# Go Doc is indenting/grouping functions unexpectedly. What is causing it?

Tags: go, godoc

Go Doc is indenting/making a group without me knowingly telling it to.

Here is a screenshot from my browser showing the problem. The four Parse functions should not be indented:

[image: Screenshot showing output of Go Doc in browser. Four of the functions are indented.]

What is causing this behaviour?

I've tried searching for indents/subsections/grouping in Go Docs but I've not found anything beside feature requests. I'm sure the answer to my question is in the documentation somewhere but I can't find it as I don't have the correct vocabulary.

I'm relatively new to Go and Go Doc, so I'm assuming the answer is something simple which I've overlooked.

---

Here is an extract of my code. Please let me know if I need to share more code.

`status.go`

```golang
package synop

// Status codes returned when parsing Blocks.
type Status int64

const (
    VALID Status = iota
    NO_DATA
    // code omitted
)

// Other functions omitted
```

`cloudwind_block.go`

```golang
package synop

import (
    "strings"
)

/*
Extract cloud cover from the cloud-wind block, Cxxxx.
Cloud, C, is the first digit of the block. Cloud over is given in [okta]:
*/
func ParseCloud(block string) (okta int, s Status) {
    slice := [2]int{0, 1}
    return parseIfValid(block, slice, str2int)
}

/*
Extract wind direction from from the cloud-wind block, xDDxxx.
Direction, DD, are the second and third digits.
*/
func ParseDir(block string) (dir string, s Status) {
    slice := [2]int{1, 3}
    return parseIfValid(block, slice, getDir)
}

// Other functions omitted
```

I have another file, `blocks.go`, which has almost the same structure as `status.go` and it does not cause this behaviour. I also don't know if the problem is caused by the preceding type `Status` or something in the `cloudwind_block.go` file.

I'm using `//` for single-line documentation and `/* */` for multi line. I've tried making this consistent on the off chance and, as expected, it had no effect.

Comment: "the answer is something simple which I've overlooked" yes ;-) go doc does the right thing automatically (see mkopriva's answer). This is not something to worry about (especially as you cannot control this at all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the grouping and indentation is that those functions are considered "constructors" of the type under which they are grouped/indented.

https://go.dev/doc/comment#func (if you scroll down a bit, you'll see this):

> This example also shows that **top-level functions returning a type T or pointer *T**, perhaps with an additional error result, **are shown alongside the type T** and its methods, under **the assumption that they are T’s constructors**.